# Filter Reset automatically when backpress

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-filter

I am facing one issue in android filter.

First of all I search some text and on the resulted value I am doing one event and come back to the activity. Once I come back that time my listview will refresh with all item rather then filtered item.

For example :
I am searching one contact from contact book and it will return some result. On that result I will do some functionality and then come back to contact listing screen that time my contact list reset automatically.

Below is the code of filter

```
public class ValueFilter extends Filter {

        ContactsAdapter adapter;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mfilterList;

        public ValueFilter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> filterList, ContactsAdapter adapter) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.mfilterList = filterList;
        }

        //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> filterListbk = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < mfilterList.size(); i++) {
                    String contactName = (String) mfilterList.get(i).get(Contacts.CONTACTKEY);
                    String contactNo = (String) mfilterList.get(i).get(Contacts.DURATION);
                    contactName = contactName.toLowerCase();
                    constraint = (CharSequence) constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    if (contactName.contains(constraint)) {
                        filterListbk.add(mfilterList.get(i));
                    }
                    if (contactNo.contains(constraint)) {
                        filterListbk.add(mfilterList.get(i));
                    }

                    results.count = filterListbk.size();

                    results.values = filterListbk;
                }

            } else {
                results.count = mfilterList.size();

                results.values = mfilterList;

            }

            return results;


        }


        //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            //  adapter.players= (ArrayList<Player>) results.values;
            adapter.Books = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) results.values;

            String new_result = results.values.toString();

            if(!new_result.equals(null)){
                adapter.Books = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) results.values;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(SipManager.ACTION_NO_RECORD_FOUND);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("result",(Serializable)adapter.Books);
                args.putSerializable("flag","0");
                intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
                /*intent.putExtra("flag","0");
                intent.putExtra("result",adapter.Books);*/
                // add data
                ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            if(new_result.equals("[]")){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(SipManager.ACTION_NO_RECORD_FOUND);
                //intent.putExtra("flag","1");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("result",(Serializable)adapter.Books);
                args.putSerializable("flag","1");
                intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);

                ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            //adapter.Books.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }
```

Below is the code of my fragment

```
public class Contacts extends Fragment implements OnBackPressListener {
    IndexFastScrollRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<String> mDataArray;
    public static boolean isVisible = false;
    ContactsAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelp;
    public static final String CONTACTID = "contactid";
    public static final String CONTACTKEY = "contactname";
    public static final String CONTACTFAV = "contactfav";
    public static final String CONTACTNUM = "contactno";
    public static final String DURATION = "duration";
    public static final String SIP = "sip";
    public static final String SIP_USER = "sip_user";


    public String sip_label = "";//"Aniphones";
    public String not_sip_label = "";
    public int flag = 0;
    public Cursor cursor;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myBooks;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myBooks1;
    public ArrayList<String> ContactSimpleList;
    public HashMap<String, Object> hm;
    public Long id;
    public String getname = "";
    public DatabaseHelper dbhelp;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    public TextView no_contacts;
    public String contact = "";
    public Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number = null;
    public PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil;
    public String dynamic_table = "";
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    String test = "", sip_user_pref = "";
    Context ctx;

    String service_start;
    private TextWatcher mSearchTw;
    private EditText etAllContSearch;
    View rootView;
    public String name = "", balance = "";
    public static final int PREMISSION_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Background_allcontacts mBackground_allcontacts = null;
    AlertDialog spotDialog = null;
    private List<AlphabetItem> mAlphabetItems;
    PrefManager pref;
    HashMap<String, String> credential;
    GlobalClass gc;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    boolean isCallPlaced = true;
    Object selectedItem;
    boolean is_called_from_filter = false;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> filterBook;


    private BroadcastReceiver mNoRecordFound = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Extract data included in the Intent
            if (intent.getAction().equals(SipManager.ACTION_NO_RECORD_FOUND)) {
                Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
                String flag = args.getString("flag");
                //String flag = intent.getExtras().getString("flag");
                if(flag.equals("1")){
                    no_contacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                else {
                    is_called_from_filter = true;
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> object = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) args.getSerializable("result");
                    filterBook = object;

                    no_contacts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Crashlytics());
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_tab, container,
                false);
        ctx = getContext();
        pref = new PrefManager(getActivity());


        mRecyclerView = (IndexFastScrollRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fast_scroller_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager = new MyCustomLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

        gc = GlobalClass.getInstance();

        no_contacts = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.no_contacts);
        spotDialog = new SpotsDialog(ctx, R.style.CustomSpotDialog);



        ctx = getContext();
        dbhelp = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        initialiseData();
        initialiseUI();
        etAllContSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAllContSearch);
        etAllContSearch.requestFocus();

        etAllContSearch.setOnTouchListener(Contacts.this);
        etAllContSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.search_icon, 0, 0, 0);

        mSearchTw = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {




                if (etAllContSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    etAllContSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.closesicon, 0);

                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);
                } else {
                    etAllContSearch.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.search_icon, 0, 0, 0);

                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(false);
                }
                if (adapter != null) {
                    //if (!adapter.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Test: Result do in search " + s);
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);

                    //}
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                if (etAllContSearch.getText().toString().length() == 0 || etAllContSearch.getText().toString() == "") {

                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);

                } else {
                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(false);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (etAllContSearch.getText().toString().length() == 0 || etAllContSearch.getText().toString() == "") {

                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);

                } else {
                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(false);

                }
            }

        };



        myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        myBooks1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        ContactSimpleList = new ArrayList<String>();

        service_start = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(Settings.PREF_SERVICE_START + "", Settings.DEFAULT_SERVICE_START);
        Log.d(TAG, "contact_sync service flag" + service_start);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "inside check permission" + service_start);
                if (service_start.equals("0")) {
                    no_contacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    no_contacts.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.synchronize_contacts));
                } else {
                    //  hideDialog();
                    no_contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println("Test: Result oncreate ");
                    if (mBackground_allcontacts == null) {
                        mBackground_allcontacts = new Background_allcontacts();
                        mBackground_allcontacts.execute();
                    }

                }
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "else " + service_start);
            if (service_start.equals("0")) {
                no_contacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                no_contacts.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.synchronize_contacts));

            } else {
                // hideDialog();
                no_contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (mBackground_allcontacts == null) {
                    mBackground_allcontacts = new Background_allcontacts();
                    mBackground_allcontacts.execute();
                }

            }
        }

        etAllContSearch.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);

        IntentFilter iFilter_NorecordFound = new IntentFilter(SipManager.ACTION_NO_RECORD_FOUND);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mNoRecordFound, iFilter_NorecordFound);

        return rootView;
    }


    protected void initialiseData() {
        //Recycler view data
        mDataArray = DataHelper.getAlphabetData();

        //Alphabet fast scroller data
        mAlphabetItems = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> strAlphabets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mDataArray.size(); i++) {
            String name = mDataArray.get(i);
            if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty())
                continue;

            String word = name.substring(0, 1);
            if (!strAlphabets.contains(word)) {
                strAlphabets.add(word);
                mAlphabetItems.add(new AlphabetItem(i, word, false));
                // mAlphabetItems.add(new AlphabetItem(i, word, false));
            }
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(i);

        }
    }


    protected void initialiseUI() {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        mRecyclerView.setIndexTextSize(12);
        mRecyclerView.setIndexBarColor("#FFFFFF");
        mRecyclerView.setIndexBarCornerRadius(0);
        mRecyclerView.setIndexBarTransparentValue((float) 0.4);
        mRecyclerView.setIndexbarMargin(0);
        mRecyclerView.setIndexbarWidth(30);

        mRecyclerView.setPreviewPadding(0);
        mRecyclerView.setIndexBarTextColor("#2d4278");
        mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, Contacts.PREMISSION_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Contacts.PREMISSION_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    // Contacts permission
                    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (service_start.equals("0")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.synchronize_contacts), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            new Background_allcontacts().execute();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void nodata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        no_contacts.setText(getString(R.string.no_sip_contacts));
        no_contacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle outState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(outState);
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.saveStates(outState);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle inState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(inState);
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.restoreStates(inState);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        isCallPlaced = true;
        pref.set_is_ongoing_call_flag(false);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        System.out.println("Test: Result onresume ");

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

        if (isVisibleToUser && this.isVisible()) {

            viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                gc.hideKeypad(getActivity());
                spotDialog.hide();

                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(etAllContSearch.getText().toString());
                    mRecyclerView.setIndexBarVisibility(true);

                }

            }

        }
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        return new BackPressImpl(this).onBackPressed();
    }

    public void getdata() {
        if (mBackground_allcontacts == null) {
            mBackground_allcontacts = new Background_allcontacts();
            mBackground_allcontacts.execute();
        }
    }

    public void getdata(String from, String value) {

        if (mBackground_allcontacts == null) {
            mBackground_allcontacts = new Background_allcontacts(from, value);
            mBackground_allcontacts.execute();

        }
    }

    //Himadri
    //Unregister all receiver when view destroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        try {
            //Here is the code for stopping some service

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }


    public class Background_allcontacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        String from;
        String value;

        public Background_allcontacts() {

        }

        public Background_allcontacts(String from, String value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.from = from;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  showDialog();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String dynamic_table = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(Settings.PREF_DYNAMIC_TABLE + "", Settings.DEFAULT_DYNAMIC_TABLE);
            if (dynamic_table != null) {
                if (!dynamic_table.equals(Settings.DEFAULT_DYNAMIC_TABLE)) {
                    cursor = dbhelp.fetchcalllog("select contact_id,contact_name,contact_num, fav,contactImage from '" + dynamic_table + "' order by UPPER(contact_name)");
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        // @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                ContactSimpleList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (cursor != null) {

                    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                        nodata();

                    } else if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                        no_contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        etAllContSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        test = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString(Settings.PREF_SIPARRAY + "", Settings.DEFAULT_SIPARRAY);

                        sip_user_pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString(Settings.PREF_SIPUSERARRAY + "", Settings.DEFAULT_SIPARRAY);
                        String[] separated = null, sipUser = null;

                        if (test != null && test.length() != 0) {
                            if (test.charAt(test.length() - 1) == ',') {
                                test = test.substring(0, test.length() - 1);
                            } else if (sip_user_pref.charAt(sip_user_pref.length() - 1) == ',') {
                                sip_user_pref = sip_user_pref.substring(0, sip_user_pref.length() - 1);
                            }

                            // Log.v("sip contacts",test);
                            if (test.contains(",")) {
                                separated = test.split(",");
                                sipUser = sip_user_pref.split(",");
                            }
                        }
                        myBooks.clear();
                        // cursor.moveToFirst();
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                            String id = "", name = "", phoneNumber = "", phoneFav = "", contactImg = "";
                            try {
                                id = cursor.getString(0);
                                name = cursor.getString(1);
                                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(2);
                                phoneFav = cursor.getString(3);
                                contactImg = cursor.getString(4);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D", "");


                            if (test.contains(",")) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < separated.length; j++) {
                                    if (Arrays.asList(separated).contains(phoneNumber)) {
                                        if (separated[j].equals(phoneNumber)) {
                                            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                            hm.put(CONTACTID, id);
                                            hm.put(CONTACTKEY, name);
                                            hm.put(DURATION, phoneNumber);
                                            hm.put(CONTACTFAV, phoneFav);
                                            hm.put("contactImage", contactImg);
                                            hm.put(SIP, sip_label);
                                            hm.put(SIP_USER, sipUser[j]);
                                            myBooks.add(hm);
                                            myBooks1.add(hm);
                                            ContactSimpleList.add(phoneNumber);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                        hm.put(CONTACTID, id);
                                        hm.put(CONTACTKEY, name);
                                        hm.put(DURATION, phoneNumber);
                                        hm.put(CONTACTFAV, phoneFav);
                                        hm.put("contactImage", contactImg);
                                        hm.put(SIP, not_sip_label);
                                        hm.put(SIP_USER, "");
                                        myBooks.add(hm);
                                        myBooks1.add(hm);
                                        ContactSimpleList.add(phoneNumber);

                                    }


                                }
                            } else {
                                if (Arrays.asList(test).contains(phoneNumber)) {
                                    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                    hm.put(CONTACTID, id);
                                    hm.put(CONTACTKEY, name);
                                    hm.put(DURATION, phoneNumber);
                                    hm.put(CONTACTFAV, phoneFav);
                                    hm.put("contactImage", contactImg);
                                    hm.put(SIP, sip_label);
                                    hm.put(SIP_USER, sip_user_pref);
                                    myBooks.add(hm);
                                    myBooks1.add(hm);
                                    ContactSimpleList.add(phoneNumber);

                                } else {
                                    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                    hm.put(CONTACTID, id);
                                    hm.put(CONTACTKEY, name);
                                    hm.put(DURATION, phoneNumber);
                                    hm.put(CONTACTFAV, phoneFav);
                                    hm.put("contactImage", contactImg);
                                    hm.put(SIP, not_sip_label);
                                    hm.put(SIP_USER, "");
                                    myBooks.add(hm);
                                    myBooks1.add(hm);
                                    ContactSimpleList.add(phoneNumber);

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Set<HashMap<String, Object>> unique = new LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Object>>(myBooks);
                    myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(unique);

                    Set<String> unique1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(ContactSimpleList);
                    ContactSimpleList = new ArrayList<String>(unique1);


                    gc.setContactsList(ctx, myBooks);
                    gc.setContactListSimpleNum(ctx, ContactSimpleList);

                    adapter = new ContactsAdapter(myBooks, getActivity(), "ALL_CONTACT", mDataArray, false);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mBackground_allcontacts = null;
                }

                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It's probably not your filter code but the hosting Activity's loading routine. Probably something you are or are not doing on `onStart()` or `onResume()` you can read more on the Android Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: yeah, I checked in code and found that on back , my activity's oncreate method will call again and in that method I have called setadapter() method so from their it will set again. To over come this issue Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Can you include your code for the actual activity? `onCreate()` only calls when the activity has been destroyed.

Comment: @Lady_A Added the code of actual fragment

Comment: We can save for example the adapter reference in the static declaration at the first time the activity is created and check it on null if we want to do something other logic on the next time the onCreated is called.

Comment: As said above, I'd only be creating the adapter if it is null. Otherwise you are resetting it - hence current behavior.

Comment: @Lady_A Thanks my problem resolved

Comment: You are welcome :)